# Cookies not saved on client while using GZip WebApi Compression

Tags: cookies, asp.net-web-api, compression, asp.net-identity, gzip

In order to save bandwidth and speeding up Http request/response, I have enabled compression (**GZip**, **Deflate**...) on `Asp.Net WebApi2.2` by adding following **package** and registering a **handler** in `WebApiConfig`.

**Package :**

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.MessageHandlers.Compression
```

**Handler :**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config, IKernel kernel)
{
       config.MessageHandlers.Insert(0, new ServerCompressionHandler(new GZipCompressor(), new DeflateCompressor()));
       .
       .
       .
}
```

Its **working fine on one of my team member's machine** but for me **it does not allow to save cookies on any of browser.**

> Is there any way to enable compression along with saving cookies?

Comment: Do you have any firewall software/virus scanner/similar installed on your system that could interfere here? (If you had this problem in one browser, I’d probably say it is a browser problem - but if you see this consistently across all browsers on one specific system, then it is more likely on an “upper level”.)

Comment: Ermm nop, have no such restriction or security implemented and it has same behavior for all browsers, seems some system related issue.Because same version of code is working fine for other team members and even on hosting server. @CBroe